# Giving error : TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python-3.x

Running this piece of code giving me error

```
data_dict = pickle.load( open("../final_project/final_project_dataset.pkl", "r") )
```

Error:

> data_dict = pickle.load( open("../final_project/final_project_dataset.pkl", "r") )
>   TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 0):

Use open with 'rb' mode instead of 'r'.

```
import pickle with open('ydata1.pkl', 'rb') as p_f:
```

`data = pickle.load(f)`